# TYPO3 trying to show a LIB, depending on the Uid, but can't get it to show

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im trying to show a LIB on some pages, but i dont want to shwo it on page UID 7.
But the lib is not showed at all, have tryed to look at the Uid 3-4-5-6 and 7.

I have this TS code.

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id <> 7]
lib.siteContact = COA
lib.siteContact {
    wrap = <div class="pagecontent-box-content" id="pagecontent-box-content-59">|</div>

    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <h2><em>Kundeservice</em></h2>

    20 = TEXT
    20.value = <img alt="" src="fileadmin/templates/add/images/kundeservice.jpg" style="width: 166px; height: 89px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" /><br />

    30 = TEXT
    30.value = <h2><em>Tlf. 69 144 145</em></h2><br />
}
[end]
```

What do i do wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no unequal sign in TypoScript conditions. One way to do negations would be to use the else statement.

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 7]
lib.siteContact = COA
lib.siteContact { 
      ...
}
[else]
      ...
[global]
```

Answer (score 1):

Show your lib on all pages and clear (or override) it if UID is 7:

```
lib.siteContact = COA
lib.siteContact {
    // rest of your code
}

[globalVar = TSFE:id = 7]
    lib.siteContact >
[end]
```